# BigQuery upload job returning errors - payload parts count wrong?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We are experiencing upload errors to BigQuery / cloud storage:

**REQUEST**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/XXX HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="PART_TAG_DATA_IMPORTER"
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 652

--PART_TAG_DATA_IMPORTER
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"configuration":{"load":{"createDisposition":"CREATE_IF_NEEDED","destinationTable":{"datasetId":"XX","projectId":"XX","tableId":"XX"},"schema":{"fields":[{"mode":"required","name":"xx1","type":"INTEGER"},{"mode":"required","name":"xx2","type":"STRING"},{"mode":"required","name":"xx3","type":"INTEGER"}]},"skipLeadingRows":1,"sourceFormat":"CSV","sourceUris":["gs://XXX/9f41d369-b63e-4858-9108-7d1243175955.csv"],"writeDisposition":"WRITE_TRUNCATE"}}}
--PART_TAG_DATA_IMPORTER--
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-GUploader-UploadID: XXX
Content-Length: 77
Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 10:23:33 GMT
Server: UploadServer
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000

Payload parts count different from expected 2. Request payload parts count: 1
```

Anyone else receiving this? Everything worked fine since last night. There were no changes in our codebase and error is happening in about 80% of the cases but after 5-6 attempts it (sometimes) goes through.

We are using .NET and have the latest Google.Apis libraries but this is reproducible by simple request to the server. It also sometimes goes through normally.

Comment: If you are sure that nothing has changed in your code and that the problem occurs only now, open a support case, maybe a feature roll out with a bug inside...

Comment: We have opened the ticket with enterprise support. They say there is an internal problem with google bigquery. They are looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has added check in `/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/jobs` endpoint a rule that it cannot receive single part message.

`/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/jobs` needs to be used when doing upload from GCS as per this documentation here (which does not say this explicitly):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert

Comment: Added some more comments to that rest documentation page, hopefully the use of the two URIs is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

This looks quite odd.  It appears you're using the inline upload endpoint but you're passing a reference to a GCS object in the load config, and not sending an inline upload.

Could you share a snippet of how you're constructing this from the .NET code?

Comment: This is fairly normal functionality. We use it all the time. Instead of added data we add uri to GCS. This was working all the time until last night.

Comment: It's completely common and expected to load data via GCS.  The expectation though is that you use the typical jobs metadata insertion endpoint e.g. `/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/jobs`.  Using a media upload endpoint (`/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/jobs`) implies you're sending both data and the job configuration using multipart mime, which is not what you're doing here.  It may be the endpoint is now enforcing this expectation.  I want to understand how the libraries are involved in constructing this request.